# How to manipulate body or html from nested layout with nextjs app routher

Tags: next.js

with the following structure

```
app/
app/layout.tsx
app/sub/layout.tsx
app/sub/page.tsx
```

how would you manipulate the html and body of the nested layout?

```
export default async function RootLayout({
    // Layouts must accept a children prop.
    // This will be populated with nested layouts or pages
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    }) {
 
    return (
        <html lang="en" className={`${capriola.variable} ${poppins.variable} ${alexbrush.variable} ${satisfy.variable} ${raleway.variable} ${workSans.variable} `} >
            <head>
                 
            </head>
            <body style={{ "--primary": "#e3154f", "--secondary": "#321575", "--light": "#321575", "--dark": "#e3154f" } as React.CSSProperties }>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

The root layout at `app/layout.tsx` is supposed to define html tags and the nested layout only adding wrapping elements, so how would i do above the right way without getting warnings that attributes already defined at render time?

I can do a "use client" component that manipulate with useffect, but that seems wrong as it will first do that on the client when rendered and i would miss out potential optimizations that the browser can do from it be defined serverside before its send to the client.